# Evaluating $\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\mathrm d(\ln x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am supposed to evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\mathrm d(\ln x)$. I solved it traditionally by simplifying the differential to $1/x . \mathrm dx$. This gives the answer as $0$. But as per the solutions, the following answer has been given to be correct.

$$\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\mathrm d(\ln x)=\int_{1/e}^{e}x^2 \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^2-e^{-2}\right)$$

I do not see why the solution should be this. Besides with a logarithm the limits of integration are $-1$ to $1$, which seems problematic. Could anyone confirm which is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Writing $d(\ln x) = \frac 1x dx$ means that you have to change the limits of the definite integration in order for the change-of-variable formula to apply. If you don't change the limit and keep it as $-1$ to $1$, you get the wrong answer.

Comment: This is contrasted with the indefinite integral case, where indeed since there are no limits, the line $d(\ln x) = \frac 1xdx$ (without further change) is correct.

Comment: You have limits of integration from $-1$ to $1$. This contains $0$ where $\ln x$ is undefined. That looks problematic to me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\ln |x|$ instead of $\ln x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@VIVID is right. Integral notation can be misleadingly concise at times, when compared with sums such as $\sum_{i=A}^{i=B}h(i)$. We need to put the equivalent of $i=$ into the limits here. When we write $\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)$,the convention is that it means $\int_{g(x)=a}^{g(x)=b}f(x)dg(x)$, which for strictly increasing $g$ becomes $\int_{x=g^{-1}(a)}^{x=g^{-1}(b)}f(x)g^\prime(x)dx=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}f(x)g^\prime(x)dx$.

Most of the time, you only encounter the case $g(x)=x$. In fairness, some sources will intend limits $a,\,b$ for $x$ instead of $g(x)$. That wouldn't work here, though, because $\ln x$ is undefined in the reals for $x\le0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering and clarifying on the general notation. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

*Note:* In this problem, $\ln x \in [-1,1]$ which implies $x \in [1/e,~e]$ (**not** $x \in [-1,1]$).

Make a substitution $(t = \ln x)$ to see what is happening:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\mathrm d(\ln x)=\int_{-1}^{1}x^2 \mathrm dt\overset{t~\to~ x}=\int_{1/e}^{e}x^2 \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|_{1/e}^e=\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2e^2}$$

Comment: But what is wrong with writing $\mathrm d(\ln x)$ as $1/x.\mathrm dx$? And what about the limits of integration being from $-1$ to $1$ with a logarithm involved?

Comment: It's not wrong, but the limits also change. When $\ln x$ is $-1$, $x$ is $1/e$, etc.

Comment: @ParasKhosla See the edit. The solution should be clearer now.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The substitution approach is really helpful. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

we have:
$$I=\int_{-1}^1x^2d(\ln x)$$
and remember that we can write this as:
$$d(\ln x)=\frac{d(\ln x)}{dx}dx=\frac1xdx$$
however, we must also consider that we have:
$$(\ln x)\in[-1,1]\Rightarrow x\in[e^{-1},e]$$

---

Another way of thinking about this problem would be using substitution, or something which i find a nice visualisation:
$$x=e^{\ln x}\Rightarrow x^2=\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^2$$
so we have:
$$I=\int_{-1}^1\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^2d(\ln x)=\left[\frac{e^{2\ln x}}{2}\right]_{\ln(x)=-1}^1$$

---

Also, try plotting a graph with $\ln x$ on the x-axis and $x^2$ on the y-axis and see what shape this forms, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The graphical approach is really helpful. Cheers :)

Comment: Your welcome. I find often in maths that calculus is well explained visually rather than just adding even more notation. I recommend the youtube channel 3blue1brown if you want to understand even more concepts in this manor

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with all the answers and agree with the OP's point-of-view.

It can be argued that the independent variable is $x$ and the integral should/could have expressly been written as

$$\int_{x=-1}^{x=1} x^2 d \ln x = \int_{x=-1}^{x=1} x\,  dx =0.$$

After all, I've seen this notation used as shorthand for integration-by-parts, and the limits referred to the independent variable ($x$) and not to a function of the variable.

The fact that $\ln x$ is not defined for $x=-1$ does not exclude the possibility that the integral is a line integral in the complex plane.  Perhaps a principal value.  Then we have other concerns (which are not insurmountable), branch points and branch cuts ...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I find the notation put forth by @J.G. in his answer to be satisfactory. I am currently studying a course that involves dealing with real valued functions only, so I am not really sure I understand the remark you make about integral representing a line integral in the complex plane. Anyways, thanks for answering. Cheers :)